# Regex Unexpected Behavior with optional groups

Tags: regex

So I have this expression

```
#(?<category>.+)(?:\/(?<id>.+))?
```

Which is supposed to capture the `foo` of `#foo` or capture both `foo` and `bar` of `#foo/bar`

However, it seems to match the entire rest of the string as `foo` and capture it
[image: RegexTester bad]

Removing the last functions as expected, but, of course, the last part is no longer optional
[image: RegexTester good]

I don't understand why this happens. (This still happens without capture groups too)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression not matching subexpression when optional](//stackoverflow.com/q/8477894/90527)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `.+` is greedy, and optional groups don't have to match.

First, `#(?<category>.+)` consumes the whole string. Then there's nothing for `(?:\/(?<id>.+))?` to match, but it's not required to match anything, so the whole expression still succeeds.

There isn't a general technique to rewrite every regex that suffers this issue, but there is a general approach to preventing it: make sure you write the preceding group to stop before the optional group would be matched. In this instance, since you want a backslash in the "id" group, you can have "category" not match backslashes:

```
#(?<category>[^/]+)(?:\/(?<id>.+))?
```

You might be tempted to use a [lazy modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy), but this still won't work, as it will then match the shortest possible substring ("f") and the optional group will still have nothing to match.

Comment: The fix is to change `.+` to `[^/]+`